Image is being rendered with 1/3 of screen width
I have a bunch of high resolution images which come with the app.
Due to app's size restrictions, I am providing a single image, instead of @3, @2, @1 images.
When I render them using
VStack{
  if let imageName = item.filename,
     let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "jpg"),
     let uiImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: bundlePath)  {
    Image(uiImage:uiImage)
      .resizable()
      .cornerRadius(20)
      .padding(.horizontal, 10)
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

    Text("bla bla bla")
  }

the image is rendered with 1/3 of the screen width, even when its original resolution is enough to fit the whole screen.
I have also tried to pack the images inside an .xcassets file and use
VStack{
  if let imageName = item.filename,
     Image(imageName)
      .resizable()
      .cornerRadius(20)
      .padding(.horizontal, 10)
      .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

    Text("bla bla bla")
  }

I want to show the image to fill the entire width, minus 10 pt of margin on each side, proportional.
What seems to be the problem?

Is your VStack taking up the entire screen? You can check in the preview by selecting the "selectable" option at the bottom (the mouse cursor next to the play button), and then clicking on the VStack in your code - it'll outline the VStack in blue.

yes, it is, because I see the text after the image filling the whole width.

what platform are you on?
try .fill instead of .fit to see what it does -
try .scaledToFit() and .scaledtoFill() -
can it be an issue with the image ratio itself?

BTW: if the images are in your assets catalogue, you can just access them by Image(imageName)

like I said, despite the fact that images are on the assets or not, they are still not scaling properly.

Currently, the code is scaling to fit, not scaling to fill.
If the aspect ratio of the image is taller than the screen then scaling to fit will fill the full height, but margins will be seen at the sides. So this might explain the appearance you are describing.
To illustrate, the example below shows an image that is built from the system symbol figure.stand.

It can be seen that the margins at the side are more than the 10pt that is being applied as horizontal padding.
For a case like this, where the aspect ratio of the image is taller than the screen, the image needs to be scaled to fill (instead of scaled to fit) in order for it to fill the full width. However, if the .aspectRatio modifier is changed to use contentMode: .fill, or if this modifier is replaced by .scaledToFill(), then the Text at the bottom gets pushed off-screen.
A general scaled-to-fill solution
To have the image fill the top part of the screen fully and then show the text below it, try applying the Image as an overlay over some kind of greedy view that consumes all the space available. Then clip the overlay to the frame of the view it is covering.
A Color can be used as the greedy view:
VStack{
    Color.clear
        .overlay {
            Image(.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    Text("bla bla bla")
}


Alternatively: scaling dependent on aspect ratio
If in fact you want tall images to be scaled-to-fill but wide images to be scaled-to-fit, try changing the overlay to use ViewThatFits:
.overlay {
    ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
        let theImage = Image(.imageName)

        theImage
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()

        theImage
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
    }
}


Maximum width, minimum height
The layout above might be suitable for some purposes. However, when the image is wide and scaled-to-fit, you might prefer the label to be shown immediately below the image, instead of at the bottom of the screen.
This can be achieved by replacing Color.clear with a footprint that is less greedy. In fact, the height of the footprint should not exceed the height needed when the image is scaled-to-fit. A hidden version of the image can be used to determine this height:
var body: some View {
    let theImage = Image(.image4)
    VStack {
        theImage
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                ViewThatFits(in: .horizontal) {
                    theImage
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()

                    theImage
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                }
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)

        Text("bla bla bla")
    }
}



